# Local Cache Library C# (persistent and encrypted)

Tags: c#, performance, caching, encryption

I'm looking to add caching to a Windows desktop application written in C# 4.

My requirements are for a persistent key-value store that saves to an encrypted file.  I am trying to cache remote calls to a server that are potentially slow—and may cache a considerable amount of data, i.e. 50+ MB.  I would like to be able to set a max-file-size value with some form of LRU expiration.

I had thought of serialising a dictionary, but this is likely to be a little slow to initialise, and will have too large a memory footprint.

I'm thinking an encrypted SQLCE 4 database might be the best solution, but this seems heavyweight when I really just want a single hash table.  It also doesn't natively offer the caching type features of expiration etc..

Can anyone suggest anything else worth considering, or some suggestion around optimising the serialisation/deserialisation.

Comment: Have you experimented with just serializing the Dictionary?  In my experience, file deserialization is normally very fast.

Comment: I haven't - the memory overhead of a 50MB+ dictionary is my concern ahead of perf

Answer (score 1):

You should absolutely consider serializing. I went round and round with this (including trying SQLCE) a few months ago and there was nothing close to the speed of serialized objects (in my case I was using custom objects) - SQLCE took 2-3 times as long to load as serialized objects.

If the memory footprint is too big, then you should reconsider how you are designing what you are persisting.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) over SQLCE 4. The SQLlite engine is explicitly designed to work in memory constrained environments. The decision of memory vs speed is left to the developer.

The [open source ADO.NET library](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) allows you to take full advantage of the Microsoft database tools (DbProviderFactory, Entity Framework, Server Explorer, etc). It also natively supports encryption.

The LRU implementation would be pretty straightforward given a schema like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE "cache" ("key" varchar(64) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "value" text NOT NULL, "last_access" datetime NOT NULL);
CREATE INDEX "cache_lru" ON "cache" ("last_access");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to look at our [SolFS](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/) library. This is a virtual file system, where you put your data into files and use the key as the file name. "Expired" file cleanup must be performed in your code, though. SolFS provides built-in encryption (and you can add your own encryption mechanisms) and is capable of holding large files (several GBs per file is perfectly fine). Moreover, SolFS also has built-in compression if you care about file size.

Answer (score 0):

To optimize the serialization, you can make your own serialization method, by implementing the interface ISerializable and turn your into XML or JSon or whatever else.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) and [File encryption in .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307010) may be useful.

You can use protobuf-net to serialize/deserialze *quickly*. (See the getting started guide for an example of persisting a 'Person' object to a binary file). protobuf also has methods that return a byte[] so you could pass this to the crypto to avoid reading the byte stream back in.